# I am making a multiple choice quiz using a txt file but dont know how to randomize the options and give a score

Tags: python, text-files

```
points = 0
with open("ComputerScience.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        y = line.split(",")
        question = y[0]
        question1 = question
        del y[0]
        random.shuffle(y)
        answer1 = y[0]
        answer2 = y[1]
        answer3 = y[2]
        answer4 = y[3]
        print(question1+"\n","(A)",answer1,"\n","(B)",answer2,"\n","(C)",answer3,"\n","(D)",answer4)
        correctans = answer1
        userans = input("Enter A,B,C,D: ")
        while userans == correctans:
            points = (points+1)
        print(points)
```

[image: This is my textfile]

[image: This is what it outputs]

How do I randomize the options and have the user to enter A B C or D and add points for every correct answer

Comment: You have written code for randomising the options, that code is not working ? What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: The first answer is the correct answer but you want to randomise them?

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: I am trying to randomize the options so that from the text file, every time you open the program options A B C D are different and the user enter A B C or D to choose the correct answer

Comment: How do you know which answer is the correct one?

Comment: The first option is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

1. Set the correct answer variable BEFORE shuffling the answers array.  Otherwise, you will get a random answer as the correct one and not the first one which is not what you appear to want.
2. Put the print at the end of your code, not in the middle of the loop, unless you want the score to be printed off after each question.
3. Finally, replace `while` with `if`.  `while` tells your code to loop as long as the `userans` variable is equal to the `correctans` variable which since neither is changed in the body of the loop will be forever.  An if statement checks the condition once.
4. You have a redundant variable declaration in your code.  (eg. just set `question1` = `y[0]` instead of using two assignments)

Bonus: Comment your code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user `correctans = answer1` line before shuffling the array.

After you have shuffled the array the value of variable answer1 has changed and it is not longer storing the correct answer(y[1]), that's why the score you are getting is 0.

Also you should use `if` statement, in place of the `while` loop because you want the user to input only one option.

Comment: Thank you I will do that but how do I get the user to enter A B C or D and pick one of those to get the correct answer

Comment: You can use the line `userans = input("Enter A,B,C,D: ")` in the while statement. This way we are asking the user to repeatedly give the answer, until the user gives the correct answer.

Comment: @Bassim I suppose you want the user to give input repeatedly, Is it so ? like if the user enters A, you want him to enter other option if the answer is not correct.

If you want the user to only enter once, user `if` in place of `while`

Comment: I want it to move to the next question every time you are done with one

Answer (score 0):

```
LETTERS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
score = 0
with open("ComputerScience.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        question, *answers = map(str.strip, s.split(','))
        answers_jumbled = random.sample(answers, len(answers))
        print(question)
        for index, answer in enumerate(answers_jumbled):
            print(f' ({LETTERS[index]}) {answer}')
        answer = None
        while answer not in LETTERS:
            answer = input("Enter A,B,C,D: ")
        if LETTERS.index(answer) == 0:
            print('Correct')
            score += 1
        else:
            print('Wrong')
print('Score:', score)
```

Comment: It says that 's' is not defined

Comment: I have got that figured out i think i changed s.split to str.split  but now I am having the problem that It is not printing the questions and the multiple choice options are not shuffled. Each question has the correct answer set to A. I want it so that every time you run the program, the correct answer changes from A to B for example or A to D.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
```

points = 0
with open("lovestory.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        z = line.split(",")
        question = z[0]
        correctans = z[-1]
        question1 = question
        y = z[1:-1]
        random.shuffle(y)
        answer1 = y[0]
        answer2 = y[1]
        answer3 = y[2]
        answer4 = y[3]
        ans = {}
        k = 0
        for choice in 'A B C D'.split():
            ans[choice] = y[k]
            k += 1

```
    print(question1+"\n","(A)",answer1,"\n","(B)",answer2,"\n","(C)",answer3,"\n"," 
          (D)",answer4)

    userans = input("Enter A,B,C,D: ")
    print('ans', ans[userans], 'act ans', correctans)

    if ans[userans] in correctans:            
        points += 1
    print('points:', points)
```

Comment: Do not know exactly how is your text file structure, used below text file

Comment: A for ?, Apple, Ball, cat, dog, Apple
B for ?, Apple, Ball, cat, dog, Ball
C for ?, Apple, Ball, cat, dog, cat

Comment: Yes that is how its structured